# Foreign key with composite key in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```
    public class ProductAttribute 
    {
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

        public Guid AttributeId { get; set; }

        public List<ProductAttributeValue> Values { get; set; }

        public object[] GetKeys()
        {
            return new object[] {ProductId, AttributeId};
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attribute
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductAttributeValue
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In origin case Product and Attribute are AggregateRoot so I want skip navigate that by property references. Value is a simple entity but I need that as list reference in my ProductAttribute class as you see that class have composite key. But I want a required relationship with cascade delete between ProductAttribute 
 and ProductAttributeValue.

This project is external module, so my fluent API configurations are extension which called in target app DbContext OnModelCreating. I should config every properties and references else didn't work.

```
        builder.Entity<ProductAttribute>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("ProductAttributes");

            b.HasKey(x => new {x.ProductId, x.AttributeId});

            //I should config ProductAttributeValue one-to-many manually here
        }

        builder.Entity<Product>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("Products");

            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        }

        builder.Entity<Attribute>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("Attributes");

            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        }

        builder.Entity<ProductAttributeValue>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable("ProductAttributeValues");

            b.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            //I should config ProductAttribute many-to-one manually here
        }
```

How can you configure your Fluent API for ProductAttribute entity to passing this scenario?

Comment: I have skipped my modelBuilder configuration because SOF

Comment: What do you mean by "that class haven't PK"? EF Core requires PK, so you probably have setup a composite PK by { ProductId, AttributeId }. And what actually is the question? Fluently defining the composite PK should be enough for EF Core to create optional shadow composite FK in `ProductAttributeValue`

Comment: @IvanStoev because this project is a external module I need to create manually builder configuration. Can you guide me how to create this shadow in `ProductAttributeValue` manually? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please Check updated version @IvanStoev

Comment: ProductAttribute doesn't have a property called `RelatedProductId`, but you're referencing that in your configuration.

Comment: Sorry, It's misspell. Fixed. I was copied wrong line. Can you help me on this? Please @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: So what's the actual problem?

Comment: Commented lines in code body! @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: @CS-Beginner Try my answer. I have perfectly generated tables  with your model classes in my side.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm on try. I know this works well in normal scenarios. But I want use configuration as extension in external app. This project haven't DbContext.

Comment: " I want use configuration as extension in external app. This project haven't DbContext" I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I also have no idea about this! :)

Comment: @CS-Beginner you are trying to add the configuration in a separate file. Is it?

Comment: in target app we can use `builer.ConfigProducts()` then all tables related to product services was generate. entities are inheritable with virtual members so I want configure all properties manually to run away any error in future ex wrong additional references in child classes @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: @TanvirArjel separate module. reusable modules top of ASP.NET core. You can check the idea behind this project at Github which is open source https://github.com/Hitasp/Tradegram

Comment: @CS-Beginner I still don't understand what's the problem (and is there a problem at all) with your model/code. In EF Core we prefer convention over configuration, and by convention your model should be ok - the `ProductAttributeValue` table should have two nullable Guid columns forming a FK. If you want a *required* relationship with cascade delete, you should tell that inside the question.

Comment: Exactly, I want a required relationship with cascade delete. Sorry for missed info. Fixed. @IvanStoev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to configure the desired relationship as required and cascade delete, you can use the following inside the `ProductAttribute` entity configuration block:

```
b.HasMany(e => e.Values)
    .WithOne()
    .IsRequired();
```

`IsRequired` is enough because by convention cascade delete is on for required and off for optional relationships. Of course you can add `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` if you want - it will be redundant, but won't hurt.

Please note that the relationships should be configured in a single place. So do it either in `ProductAttribute` or `ProductAttributeValue`, but never in both (error prone, may cause unexpected conflicting or overriding configuration issues).

For completeness, here is how you can configure the same inside `ProductAttributeValue` configuration (requires explicitly providing the `HasOne` generic type argument due to the lack of navigation property):

```
b.HasOne<ProductAttribute>()
    .WithMany(e => e.Values)
    .IsRequired();
```

Comment: Actually you proposed the same thing what I did just with some explanation and from different entity. By the way,Thank you.

Comment: @TanvirArjel The difference is that (1) I first clarified the OP issue before proposing a solution and (2) I don't propose model changes and your answer still contains invalid line `.HasForeignKey(pa => new {pa.ProductId, pa.AttributeId}` - a leftover from the proposed model changes in your initial answer of the unknown issue :) Other than that, it's not an idea and not a proposal - just a proper usage of the necessary fluent API for OP model/requirements :)

Comment: Sometimes model changes is needed just for the readability. Already I have clarified this in my answer comment section. Look at if you take my previous answer then the foreign keys (composite) in the table `ProductAttributeValues` would have been  `ProductId` and `AttributeId`. Now it will generate as `ProductAttributeProductId` and `ProductAttributeAttributeId` due to the shadow property. That's why I personally prefer explicit property. You cannot say my approach is wrong! May be you like different approach.

Comment: More importantly! not all questioner are high level expert like you. That's why I always try to make things explicit and clear instead of implicit. :)

Answer (score 10):

Write your `ProductAttribute` configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAttribute>(b =>
{
    b.ToTable("ProductAttributes");

    b.HasKey(x => new {x.ProductId, x.AttributeId});

    b.HasMany(pa => pa.Values).WithOne().IsRequired();
});
```

But there is a concern of readability. This will add the columns `ProductAttributeProductId` and `ProductAttributeAttributeId` as composite foreign key to the table `ProductAttributeValues` for the [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties). If you want to make composite foreign key in table `ProductAttributeValues` more readable then you can update your model `ProductAttributeValue` model class as follows:

```
public class ProductAttributeValue
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    public Guid AttributeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then update the `ProductAttribute` configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductAttribute>(b =>
{
    b.ToTable("ProductAttributes");

    b.HasKey(x => new {x.ProductId, x.AttributeId});

    b.HasMany(pa => pa.Values).WithOne().HasForeignKey(pa => new {pa.ProductId, pa.AttributeId});
});
```

Now composite foreign key in table `ProductAttributeValues` will be generated as `ProductId` and `AttributeId`.

Thank you.

Comment: I would change the key to `b.HasKey(x => new {x.ProductId, x.AttributeId, x.Id});` to simplify the indexing.

Comment: Yes! can be! Thank you! Let see what the OP think about the answer!

Comment: Noticed that you are always proposing OP model changes. It's not necessary. None of the changes are mandatory. The desired FK relationship can be defined with just fluent API. Or no configuration/model changes at all - what is the problem with OP model/code? It's unclear form the question and the answer. The answer should point to the problem and then provide a solution, rather than just say "do this".

Comment: I think what @IvanStoev is getting at is that this scenario explicit configuration is not really necessary, as EF Core conventions will result in a similar model, just with Shadow Properties instead of explicit properties for the Foreign Key.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties  The core enhancement that Shadow Properties deliver is that you really can omit Foreign Key properties from your entities, whereas in EF6 they were almost always necessary.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But columns in the database table will be generated for shadow properties, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  And they will be loaded and available to the Change Tracker, and through the Change Tracker to the programmer.  You just don't have to see them on your Entities if you don't want to.

Comment: Yes! I know this and that's why I personally prefer there should properties for the columns in the database table to make it more readable. Okay!  that's the personal choice. Thank you all again.