# EF Core double primary key

Tags: asp.net, ef-core-2.2

I have a project with my school, I have to make a website like stackoverflow (possibility to add a question, a member can answer or put a comment if he have enough reputation, etc).

I have an issue with the class `Vote`. It should have 2 primary keys (the user and the post), but I don't know how to do that with EF Core.

Thank you for your help !

[image]

Comment: To be precise - it's still just **ONE** primary key (since a table in a relational database can **NEVER** have more than one PK!) - but it's made up from **two columns** .....

Comment: Duplicate (but now the *question* is your answer): https://stackoverflow.com/q/54441615/861716

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use fluent API:

```
.HasKey(vote => new { vote.upvoteId, vote.downvoteId});
```

Please take a look at the `.HasKey()` method
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method

Hope this helps!