# EF Core Configure Model with Two Primary Keys from Separate Tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor, composite-primary-key

The title of this post suggests this may be a simple scenario like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289243/14024210) but it's actually a bit more complicated.

I'm working on a Blazor site that will serve as a new frontend to an existing set of tables. There is a table of company `Clients` with a primary key called `ClientId`.

There are also `Users`, which represent company employees, with a primary key of `UserId`.

All of the columns in `Client` are stored in this table with the exception of the client's relationship to the user (good relationship, don't know them well, etc.). In the existing `EmployeeRelationship` table, the `ClientId` and `UserId` both serve as the primary key, as the `EmployeeRelationship` is dependent on both the `Client` and `User`. This is fine but I have been unable to make EF Core accept this relationship.

What I'd like to do is add the `EmployeeRelationship` property to my `Client` object such that I can reference it like `Client.EmployeeRelationship.Description`. The problem then is the `User` object, as EF has no idea what to do with the secondary PK on `EmployeeRelationships` if I call `.Include`, as there is no FK for `User` in the `Client` object.

Would it be possible to provide this foreign key when I call `Include` on `Client`?

For example, something like:

```
Context.Clients.Select(x => x).Include(x => EmployeeRelationship, UserId);
```

Where {UserId} can be used to provide the missing foreign key.

If not, how can I get around this issue? I also find it odd that whoever created this table used the UserId and ClientId as the primary key because it means the User/Client tables share the same name for the PK, but I'm not sure if this is a problem. It seems like the UserId and ClientId should be foreign keys but this still wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: What is the type of the `Client` -> `EmployeeRelationship` relationship? The way you explain the `EmployeeRelationship` table it looks like one-to-**many**, so there is no single `EmployeeRelationship` per `Client`, but multiple, which is represented with `ICollection<EmployeeRelationship> EmployeeRelationships` property rather than `EmployeeRelationship EmployeeRelationship` property you are asking for.

Comment: It's technically a one to many relationship, yes. I was hoping to access it as a one to one relationship as there is one employee relationship per Client/User _pairing_. I don't  care about the other relationships. You may have given me an idea, though. I could define EmployeeRelationship as an ICollection as you described and when I used `.Include`, [filter the included results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147681/14024210)? That way I would only get the relationship I need instead of every other relationship.

Comment: Sure you can. An then use `FirstOrDefault()` to access the single item. Actually there is no other way so far since EFC does not support "logical" navigations. Or "skip" navigations other than collection to collection for M2M.

Comment: Seems to be working as I need it to, thanks!